# Can I create my own custom Mapper.Option in datastax java driver for cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I wanted to create my own custom Mapper.Option type while using DataStax java driver for Cassandra, to modify statements as per my needs. When i see Mapper.Option.class it has Type as enum which cannot be changed to add my own Type. Is there any other way i can do it?

Comment: What configurability were you looking to add?  There may be an alternative to what you are trying to do.

Comment: When i save an entity, I wanted to make entry into another table (Joining table. In Cassandra this will created based on required query). As it will be good to add it with batch statement for guaranteed insert, I would like to modify the INSERT INTO query to convert into Batch statements with multiple insert statements.

Comment: I think I can do it by using mapper.saveQuery(entity). That will do the job. Thanks for reply.

Comment: But it will be better using Mapper.Option, as i can set default options and no need to build a wrapper on Mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Not without making changes to the driver, but the driver is always open to contributions ([contributors guide](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/CONTRIBUTING.md)).   If interested in incorporating something, it would be a good idea to open up a [JIRA](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/projects/JAVA/issues) ticket first or send an email to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!forum/java-driver-user).